# LLDB (Swift 3) Listing User Defined Variable

Tags: swift3, xcode8, lldb

When debugging, I am able to set an user defined variable using `e -l Swift -- let $foo = unsafeBitCast(0x12345678, to: UIView.self)`.

If after make a few such calls, is it possible to get a list of user defined variables back showing their current values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not currently a way to list all the user defined variables/types.  Please file an enhancement request with http://bugreporter.apple.com, it shouldn't be hard to add.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing is the `variable viewer` next to Xcode's debug console. If you click on tab button to the right of the trash can icon at the bottom of Xcode this will expand the view.

[image]

Setting breakpoints in your application will display your executable variable names and values at that current time and show you in the `variables viewer`.

[image]

Comment: Those are variables in your program.  The lldb expression parser allows you to add variables on the fly.  Those are the variables that Maarut wanted to see, and those do not show up in the variables viewer.